# Blind spots in Windows 7 search

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, search-indexing

Despite running the indexer for 48 hours, Windows 7 Search still ignores many files, especially those added within the last two weeks. I have 644,000 indexed items. I'm not sure whether I should delete and rebuild the index for fear of not being able to search for anything. The folder in which I'm searching has 2,500 files. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: In Control Panel, Index Options, first screen when you open this, are the Locations shown what you need for your files (specially USERS and Outlook)?  If not, add the locations you need and rebuild the index again.

Comment: I know about index options. What I don't know is whether there's any way to force the index to recognize a file by pointing to it and clicking a function such as 'add to the index" or a command.

Comment: "is whether there's any way to force the index to recognize a file by pointing to it"  <-- I do not think so. Index Option methodology has been pretty stable over the years.